# Counting occurence in nested JSON object

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop

Given five lists as follows:

```
make = ['ford', 'fiat', 'nissan', 'suzuki', 'dacia']
model = ['x', 'y', 'z']
version = ['A', 'B', 'C']
type = ['sedan', 'coupe', 'van', 'kombi']
infos = ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine', 'throttle problems', None]
```

And JSON object:

```
data = [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'make': 'ford',
                'model': 'x',
                'version': 'A',
                'type': 'sedan',
                'infos': [
                            {
                                "id": 999,
                                "name": 'steering wheel problems'
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 99,
                                "name": 'broken engine'
                            }
                ],
                'owner':
                            {
                                "id": 999,
                                "name": 'alice'
                            },
                "type":
                            {
                                "value": 987,
                                "id": 129,
                                "name": 'A',
                                "type": 'zaz'
                            }
            },
            ...
    ]
```

I need to iterate and create JSON object containing fields with all possible combinations of items in such lists and number of their occurences in object `data` meaning that a car with particular make, model, version, type and with particular infos (not only one infos item but can be multiple or even whole infos list) is of certain amount - let's say there are 2 cars like these. I expect something like this:

```
total = [
            {
                'make': 'ford',
                'model': 'x',
                'version': 'A',
                'type': 'sedan',
                'infos': [
                        {
                        'inf': 'steering wheel problems'
                        }
                ],
                'occurence': 0
            },
            ...
            {
                {
                'make': 'dacia',
                'model': 'z',
                'version': 'C',
                'type': 'kombi',
                'infos': [
                        {
                        'inf': 'steering wheel problems'
                        },
                        {
                        'inf': 'gearbox problems'
                        },
                        {
                        'inf': 'broken engine'
                        },
                        {
                        'inf': 'throttle problems'
                        }                        
                ],
                'occurence': 1
            }
         ]
```

My attempt looks like:

```
for i in infos:
        for j in make:
            for k in model:
                for m in version:
                    for n in type:
                        s = sum([1 for p in data if (data['infos'] == i and data['make'] == j and data['model'] == k and data['version'] == m and data['type'] == n))
                        total.append({'infos': i, 'make': j, 'model': k, 'version': m, 'type': n, 'occurence': s})
return total
```

But I'm stuck especially with iterating over `infos`. How to write correct code in such problem?

Comment: What are you stuck on? What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "iterating over infos"? And more importantly, what exactly are you stuck on? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: This is a common error. I suggest you google that exact message to see what solutions others already suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you want to make a dictionary of all the combinations of make, model, type, and version, and all combinations of info as separate dictionary entries.  You can use combinations and product from itertools to make the dictionary, then you can go through all the data entries to check if its in the dictionary and then count it.  If you didn't want combinations that aren't in the data, you can use a Counter.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

info_combos = [combo for n in range(1, len(infos)+1) for combo in combinations(infos, n)]

total = {(ma, mo, v, t, tuple(i)): 0 for ma, mo, v, t, i in product(make, model, version, types, info_combos)}

for car in data:
    if all([car['make'] in make, 
            car['model'] in model, 
            car['type'] in types, 
            car['version'] in version]):
        # assuming infos in data are ordered:
        key = tuple([car['make'],
                     car['model'], 
                     car['version'], 
                     car['type'], 
                     tuple([i['name'] for i in car['infos']])])
        total[key] += 1
```

This would be quite slow, as your dictionary or Counter would get exponentially larger with more entries in makes and models, and and with large datasets as you're looping through everything.

Comment: Using this I'm running into: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\proj\proj.py", line 219, in <module>
    for ma, mo, v, t, i in product(make, model, version, types, info_combos)}
  File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\proj\proj.py", line 219, in <dictcomp>
    for ma, mo, v, t, i in product(make, model, version, types, info_combos)}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I forgot to change these into a hashable object as dictionaries can't be made as the keys.  You have to make the keys as tuples, not dictionaries.

Comment: Another error occured: File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\proj\proj.py", line 228, in <module>
    total[key] += 1
KeyError: ('ford', 'x', 'A', ('steering wheel problems', 'broken engine'))

Comment: it looks like it's making a key without the car's type; one issue you could be running into is naming a variable 'type' as this is a built-in name, use something different (I used 'types' in mine.  Be sure both the creation of the keys for the dictionary and the creation of the key for each car is the same, it may be that you're missing adding the type when making a car's key into the dictionary.

Comment: check that your dataset doesn't have two keys as 'type' on the same level, which it looks like it may.  It counts them on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If guess you mean that your test `data['infos'] == i` is never evaluated to `True`.
Here you probably want to check that you must have in the `infos` field of your dictionary an item `x` such that `x['name'] == i`.
If that's your problem you can instead replace your `sum` by:

```py
s = sum(
   1 for p in data
   if any(x['name'] == i for x in p['infos'])   # test replaced here
      and p['make'] == j
      and p['model'] == k
      and p['version'] == m
      and p['type'] == n
)
```

Note that your solution is going to be excessively slow since you'll need to traverse your whole list for each possible tuple `(name, make, model, version, type)`.